# Getting node-hid working in Windows

Tags: node.js, hid, hidapi

I'm trying to get the node-hid (https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid) module working on Windows 7.  I can open a device and write to it, but no data ever arrives.

I've verified the device is sending data.  I've dug through the node-hid code (HID.cc) and tried several things to get it working:

- Modified the HID::recvAsync function to use an hid_read_timeout in a loop to see if that would return anything.
- Set both blocking and non-blocking.
- Changed buffer sizes to exactly fit what the device sends.

On Windows 8, with the hid_read_timeout call change, this all works fine.  I'm not sure what may have changed between the two systems, but I plan on using this on windows XP as well, so I can't just call it good.

I'm struggling to come up with more ideas as to how to debug this issue.  Has anyone successfully done this before?  Is there a better option to use Node.js with an HID device?

Comment: Have you tried something like Snoopy to see if your data is making it to the device?  When you did `npm install` did everything build correctly?

Comment: In answer to Brad, yes, the messages are making it both ways as I've tested it with other code utilizing HIDAPI.

Oddly, trying this on a windows 8 computer I have works once I've made the code use the hid_read_timeout call.  I'm beginning to wonder if my habit of not restarting my Windows 7 machine is coming to bite me.   I'll post when I can get back to that machine with an update.

Comment: I never restart either... unless working with hardware.  I've had weird issues with USB chipsets where things just don't work properly.  You might be on to something there.

Comment: Well, tested on the Windows 7 machine and it still doesn't work.  Same code as before.  Very bizarre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some serious debugging, I found that for some reason I have as of yet not been able to determine, the source file, HID.cc for the node module node-hid needed a call to hid_init() within the constructor before the hid_open call.  I'm assuming that somehow this is getting hit with multiple threads, making the safety of calling hid_init before hid_open necessary.

I now have this working on both windows 7 and windows 8.

Summary of changes I had to make:
Add hid_init before the hid_open call I'm using.
Change hid_read to hid_read_timeout in a loop. (Since reads won't return on windows XP when shutting down otherwise.)

Once I've cleaned it up, I'll send the author my changes.

Comment: I have the exact same issue but I am unable to fix it on windows 10 even when I added a call to hid_init() before hid_open(). I compiled it and it still shows me the error "can't open device with path". I am trying to use a "unitech" barcode scanner which shows up as a keyboard. Is there a work around for this or no.